# how to insert a landscape subview in portrait view,just like VEVO

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

I have a tableview which I want it in portrait mode.And when I select a row, I want the subview in landscape mode, just like VEVO. In VEVO's videos, the tableView is only portrait,when select a row,the view is only landscape.

As far as I knoow ,that

A UINavigationController will only autorotate if its root view controller is also set to autorotate. 
A UITabBarController will only autorotate if all of its view controllers are set to autorotate.

so I cant use navigationController, am I right?
so I can only use addsubview,but how it works?
I set tableview  ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortait,and subview ==landscapeLeft||right,but subview is still not work correctly, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply transform to your view. It doesn't matter how you are adding your view as the `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;` method will not be called if your tabBarController will not support autorotation. You'll actually need to hide the status bar as it will not rotate to represent your orientation. I've used to do that as I was asked to do, but it was buggy and thanks to God my boss have changed his way to portrait orientation only.